# Eclipse CDT Indigo CLOCKS_PER_SEC could not be resolved issue

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

I dont know if this is a bug or i am the only one facing this,

In Eclipse CDT indigo, create a new C++ executable project and create a CPP file in a C++ source folder.i.e. src/test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    clock_t strt = clock();
    int i = 2;
    clock_t end = clock();
    cout<<(end-strt)*1000.0f/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return 0;
}
```

now see that the CLOCKS_PER_SEC is unresolved, but project compiles sucessfully and runs fine too. I am on ubuntu 10.10 64 bit. Is this a bug or some settings screw up ( indexer? ) ?

Comment: Same thing happens for when starting a C project in Eclipse CDT.

Answer (score 10):

You can manually add the time.h to the indexer, go to Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer and put it in front of the existing "Files to be indexed up-front" like this:

```
time.h, cstdarg, ...
```

Then it should work just fine.

Comment: It worked. I think this is strange because `ctime` is already included in the to-be-indexed files list, however replacing it with `time.h` actually solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in CDT: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351549. It might have been fixed in the [nightly build](https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/cdt-nightly/).

Answer (score 0):

My eclipse behaves exact the same way. I think it's something about indexer.

Comment: So the answer is as soon as it compiles and its working there is nothing unresolved. It's just some eclipse bug or the indexer isn't parsing the #defines in the <time.h>

Answer (score 0):

comment no.17 on this bug report worked for me

Project->Properties->Indexer:
   "Files to index up-front"
            **Put ctime at the beginning of the list.**

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351549