# Field tv_sec could not be resolved

Tags: c++, g++, time.h

I am trying to run the following code snippet taken from [this simple example of a timer](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/03/14/create-a-timer/):

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int SetTimer(struct timeval &tv, time_t sec) {
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    tv.tv_sec += sec;

    return 1;
}

int CheckTimer(struct timeval &tv, time_t sec) {
    struct timeval ctv;
    gettimeofday(&ctv, NULL);

    if ((ctv.tv_sec > tv.tv_sec)) {
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        tv.tv_sec += sec;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct timeval tv;
    SetTimer(tv, 5); //set up a delay timer
    printf("start counting.\n");
    while (1)
        if (CheckTimer(tv, 5) == 1)
            printf("Welcome to cc.byexamples.com\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am obtaining the following error: field `tv_sec` could not be resolved

I have searched for it on the Web but no one seems to give a concrete answer.

I tried my chance looking into the libraries `sys/time.h` and `time.h` but in none of them seems to be defined this structure but is anyway used.

Am I missing any library? Since this example is rather old, did something changed that needs it to be done in a different way? I would appreciate any sight.

PS: I am using Eclipse CDT Indigo under Ubuntu 11.10 and g++ 4.6.1.

Comment: Please include the code in your question (there are at least two code samples at the link you pointed to) and show us the exact error message, including the reported line number. The first example compiles for me with g++ (after I change `&gt;` to `>` due to a copy-and-paste problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was an Eclipse problem since it was unable to index the `time.h` library. I solved it by following the most upvoted answer of [this other SF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476373/eclipse-cdt-indigo-clocks-per-sec-could-not-be-resolved-issue):

Adding manually `time.h` to the C/C++ indexer.

Currently I am using Eclipse CDT Juno and the problem doesn't seems not to be happening anymore. As a side comment in Eclipse CDT Juno I couldn't find the location where to manually edit the C/C++ indexer settings.

Answer (score 0):

try to put this in your file :  #define __USE_GNU

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already tried that since the structure seems to be available only when the it exist such definition, but it gives me this: warning: "__USE_GNU" redefined [enabled by default]